# Jquery Find list elements with class and hide everything else

Tags: jquery, list, find

I would like to create a jquery filter that finds list elements with a certain class and then hides (every other list element)

The code below finds li items with a class and hides them - but I want to do the opposite.  (not quite sure how to do this)

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10fq6k1a/2/) I've setup.    Many thanks for any help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mbodysub').on('click', '#editfilter', function(e) {
     console.log('filter clicked');
     
     //want to do the opposite, just show li where child div has .editcolor class
     $('.mbodysub ul').find(".editcolor").parent('li').toggle();

   })
   $('.mbodysub').on('click', '#tsfilter', function(e) {
     console.log('filter clicked');
     $('.mbodysub ul').find(".tscolor").parent('li').toggle();

   })
   $('.mbodysub').on('click', '#rolefilter', function(e) {
     console.log('filter clicked');
     $('.mbodysub ul').find(".rolecolor").parent('li').toggle();

   })
   });
```

This is a typical list element

```html
<li id="194" class="external changecss">
          <div class="acl_title" style="overflow:hidden">
            <div id="2137" class="remove">[X]</div>
            <img style="float:left" src="/images/user32.png" width="32" height="32">
            <h3>Jeff Bloggs</h3>
            <p>Program Manager</p>
          </div>
          <div class="colorline editor editcolor"></div>
          <div class="colorline ts"></div>
          <div class="colorline role rolecolor"></div>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could negate `li` elements that have a `.editcolor` descendant by combining the [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors:

```
$('.mbodysub ul li:not(:has(.editcolor))').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer.

```
$('li').not('.editcolor').toggle();
```

That finds all li elements, filters out all elements that have the class of 'editcolor', and then toggles the remaining elements.